# Angular post call not working (Getting 415 error)

Tags: javascript, angular, http, http-headers, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to fetch the response from the below code. Which gives the JSON output.  In server i'm getting `415` issue and the response also not coming.

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

 public getReports(postData: IRreq) {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(sampleurl, JSON.stringify(postData), { headers: headers })    
    .pipe(map((res:any) => this.report = res));

};
```

[image: Response]

No issue from the API, getting 200 and response in postman. Not sure what was the issue here, need some help on this. Thanks

Comment: 415 stands for `Unsupported Media Type`.  Are you sending your payload as `application/json` as well in Postman? Any case in witch your api returns 415 on purpose?
Without more information I have no other ideas

Comment: Removing the JSON.stringify could fix it

Comment: @Doc . Yes i'm sending the payload as `application/json`  in postman.

Answer (score 0):

You are using example for Angular 2. That times json content-type was not standard way.

Now when you want to make request with json content-type you only do following:

```
const body = { title: "Angular PUT Request Example" };
this.http
  .put<any>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", body)
  .subscribe((data) => console.warn(data));
```

So you don't need to do any magic with json encoding etc.